# Why can a QObject not be set as parent of a QWidget?

Tags: qt, inheritance, qt5, parent-child, qwidget

Is it possible to set a QObject as parent of a QWidget, so the QWidget is deleted when the QObject is deleted?

The following code doesn't compile:

```
QObject a;
QObject b;
QWidget c;

b.setParent(&a); // This works
c.setParent(&a); // This fails: error C2664: 'void QWidget::setParent(QWidget *,Qt::WindowFlags)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'QObject *' to 'QWidget *'
```

Even though QWidget inherits from QObject! So why is the `setParent(QObject*)` function not available in QWidget anymore?

Comment: There's no need to do that. Add the widget as a by-value member in the parent object, or use a by-value late initialization trick.

Comment: Great idea, thanks!

Comment: Another way, if you must create widgets with `new` for some reason, is to connect "parent" QObject's `destroyed` signal to widget's `deleteLater` slot.

Comment: Cool idea, thanks. I ended up using the "Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose" in the end, though...